# Geoserver Password Forgotten

Tags: geoserver

I have forgotten my GeoServer login id & password. Is there any way to restore default password? Or is there any way to view the password?

Comment: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/security/passwd.html

Comment: More details are needed, like the type of account you're referring to and the server configuration, to answer this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is located in a security file. Details from [here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/gettingstarted/web-admin-quickstart/index.html)

> Logging In
>
> In order to change any server settings or configure data a user must first be
>   authenticated. Navigate to the upper right hand corner to log into GeoServer. 
>   The default username and password is admin and geoserver. These can be changed 
>   by editing the security/users.properties file in the [GeoServer Data Directory](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/index.html#data-directory).

Answer (score 1):

unless you already set a custom password, default username and password for geoserver localhost:8080/geoserver/ are

> username:
> admin
>
> password:
> geoserver

If this is not the case, [geoserver-users.narkive.com](https://geoserver-users.narkive.com/rDV1AUhb/forgot-the-geoserver-login-password) indicates:

> If you have write access to the data directory and have not set a
> master password, you can change the admin password by editing
> **security/usergroup/default/users.xml**
>
> Change the line like this:
>
> ```
> <user enabled="true" name="admin"
> password="digest1:D9miXH/hVgfxZJscMbfXtbtliG0WOxhLfsznyWfG38X2pda2JOSV4POi55PQI4tw"/>
> ```
>
> To:
>
> ```
> <user enabled="true" name="admin" password="plain:PASSWORD"/>
> ```
>
> where `PASSWORD` is your new temporary password in plain text. I do
> not think you need to restart GeoServer.