# Geoserver admin credentials lost , Is there a way to retrieve it?

Tags: geoserver, administration, password

We had setup Geoserver within our internal server and change the default credentials.
Now due to some circumstances we have lost the geoserver admin credentials, is there anyway to retrieve the same.

Also is there a way we can reset the admin credentials, i.e. admin/Geoserver

Comment: Does this help https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103324/geoserver-password-forgotten

Comment: @AmanBagrecha, That didnt help, as there was no folder with that name